# Prime but not maximal ideal in k[x,y] is principal

Tags: abstract-algebra, algebraic-geometry, commutative-algebra

> Prime ideal in $k[x,y]$, which is not maximal, is generated by one element. ($k$ is a field)

Why it is true? I know that dimension of $k[x,y]$ is equal 2 and also that $k[x,y]$ is UFD. I have problems to connect these two facts. I would like any hint.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A non-zero prime ideal in a dimension $2\,$ U.F.D. which is not maximal has height $1$. Furthermore, every non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in a U.F.D. contains a prime element $p$, by a theorem of Kaplansky. So $(p)\subset\mathfrak p$ and both have height $1$: necessarily $(p)=\mathfrak p$.

Comment: Your first sentence does not make sense in general.

Comment: @MooS: You're right. I had in mind the case of $k[X,Y]$. I've completed my sentence. Thanks for pointing  the problem!

Comment: I think I've already seen this claim: *every non-zero prime ideal $\mathfrak p$ in a U.F.D. contains a prime element $p$* attributed to Kaplansky. This is a trivial fact for UFDs. It occurs in Kaplansky's criterion for UFDs, but ...